# How to get woocommerce cart item names as array

Tags: php, arrays, woocommerce

I was wondering how to get all the items in my cart as an array. 
I need this because I have to use `array_intersect`, this way I can compare them.

I haven't found anything about this on the internet.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the cart contents through the `WC()->cart` object, like so:

```
<?php
$cart_contents = WC()->cart->cart_contents;
$cart_item_names = array();
foreach($cart_contents as $item) {
    array_push($cart_item_names, $item['data']->post->post_title);
}
```